# Shared element transition in between fragments of different activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I am trying to achieve shared element transition between two **FixedAspectImageView** which lie under different fragments of different activity. Destination is also under **NestedScollView**
What all is happening is just a flicker at **Fragment1** with slight transition and than loading of **Fragment2** in Activity2.

Since the elements lie under fragments of different activity, have tried using **postponeEnterTransition()** in on create of Activity2 and             **startPostponedEnterTransition()** in onCreateView of Fragment2.

```
OriginLayout:
<CardView>
   <LinearLayout>
       <FrameLayout>
           <FixedAspectImageView>
              transitionName:"image"


DestinationLayout:
<FrameLayout>
   <NestedScrollView>
       <LinearLayout>
           <FrameLayout>
               <FixedAspectImageView>
                  transitionName:"image"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing `startPostponedEnterTransition()` too early: in on `onCreateView` your view hasn't yet been created and laid out. Neither it is in `onViewCreated()`, which is called right after `onCreateView()`.

Instead, you have to wait until the view is laid out using either [`ViewTreeObserver` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178461/1083957) or plain `view.post(Runnable)`, and only then perform `startPostponedEnterTransition()`.